# Geometry of the covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose a random vector X is given in (a real or complex vector space) V. If two basis for V are chosen, and X decomposed into 2 lists of random variables, what is the relationship between the two covariance matrices? (Is there anything geometric , I.e. coordinate free?)

By a random vector I mean a measurable function from $\Omega \to V$, where $\Omega$ is a sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that both bases are fixed. If $X_1,X_2$ are the two decompositions of $X$, then $X_2=PX_1$ where $P$ is invertible. Finally $\operatorname{cov}(X_2) = P \operatorname{cov}(X_1) P^T$. In particular, $\operatorname{cov}(X_1)$ and $\operatorname{cov}(X_2)$ have same signature.